# Dagger 2 DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2, mvp

I have found many similar questions but no one solve my problem can some one please  guide me what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to sole this error last two days but no luck.

Here is my Code setup.

**DashboardMenuContract.java**

```
public interface DashboardMenuContract {

interface View{
void getAllDashboardMenuSucces(ArrayList<DashboardmenuModel> dashboardmenuModels);
void getAllDashboardMenuFailure(String message);
}
interface Presenter{
void getDashboardMenus();
}
interface Interactor{
void getAllDashboardMenusFromApi();
}

interface OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener{
void onGetAllDashboardMenuSucces(ArrayList<DashboardmenuModel> dashboardmenuModels);
void onGetAllDashboardMenuFailure(String message);
}
}
```

*DashboardMenuPresenter.java*

```
 public class DashboardMenuPresenter implements DashboardMenuContract.Presenter, DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener {

        private DashboardMenuContract.View view;
        private DashboardMenuInteractor dashboardMenuInteractor;

        @Inject
        public DashboardMenuPresenter(DashboardMenuContract.View view,DashboardMenuInteractor dashboardMenuInteractor) {
            this.view = view;
            this.dashboardMenuInteractor = dashboardMenuInteractor;
        }
}
```

*DashboardMenuInteractor.java*

```
public class DashboardMenuInteractor implements DashboardMenuContract.Interactor {
    private final ArrayList<DashboardmenuModel> dashboardmenuModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener onGetAllDashboardMenuListener;
    @Inject
    public DashboardMenuInteractor(DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener onGetAllDashboardMenuListener) {
        this.onGetAllDashboardMenuListener = onGetAllDashboardMenuListener;
    }
}
```

*MainActivityMvpModule.java*

```
@Module
public class MainActivityMvpModule {
    private  DashboardMenuContract.View mView; 

    public MainActivityMvpModule(DashboardMenuContract.View mView) {
        this.mView = mView; 
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    public DashboardMenuContract.View providesView(){
        return mView;
    } 



    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    DashboardMenuContract.Interactor provideInteractor(DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener onGetAllDashboardMenuListener){
        return new DashboardMenuInteractor(onGetAllDashboardMenuListener);
    }


    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    DashboardMenuPresenter providePresenter(DashboardMenuContract.View mView,DashboardMenuInteractor dashboardMenuInteractor){
        return new DashboardMenuPresenter(mView,dashboardMenuInteractor);
    } 
}
```

*The error trace*

```
E:\AndroidStudio\Motivation\app\src\main\java\motivation\com\motivation\component\DashboardMenuComponent.java:18: error: motivation.com.motivation.core.dashboardmanu.DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
    void injectMainActivity(MainActivity mainActivity);
         ^
      motivation.com.motivation.core.dashboardmanu.DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener is injected at
          motivation.com.motivation.core.dashboardmanu.DashboardMenuInteractor.<init>(onGetAllDashboardMenuListener)
      motivation.com.motivation.core.dashboardmanu.DashboardMenuInteractor is injected at
          motivation.com.motivation.module.MainActivityMvpModule.providePresenter(…, dashboardMenuInteractor)
      motivation.com.motivation.core.dashboardmanu.DashboardMenuPresenter is injected at
          motivation.com.motivation.MainActivity.dashboardMenuPresenter
      motivation.com.motivation.MainActivity is injected at
          motivation.com.motivation.component.DashboardMenuComponent.injectMainActivity(mainActivity)
```

Comment: Where did you defined DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener provider?

Comment: there is my `OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener` interface which is within `DashboardMenuContract` interface. if you want to check then I will update it

Comment: @DhavalPatel please check I updated the question

Comment: That is just defination, But dagger is not able to find DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener provider from module.

Comment: I'm no expert in dagger but adding below code in MainActivityMvpModule might solve your problem:

@Provides
DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener provideGetAllDashboardMenuListener (DashboardMenuPresenter presenter){
 return (DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener)presenter;
}

Comment: when i update my  MainActivityMvpModule with your code getting this error `error: Found a dependency cycle:`

Comment: Becauase *DashboardMenuPresenter* depends on *DashboardMenuInteractor* and *DashboardMenuInteractor* depends on *DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListen(DashboardMenuPresenter)*

Comment: So what should I do @DhavalPatel

Comment: You can remove  *DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener onGetAllDashboardMenuListener* from DashboardMenuInteractor.

Comment: Or if it requires set DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener through method in DashboardMenuInteractor. Not constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide listener in your MainActivityMvpModule. Maybe you should cast `dashboardMenuPresenter`.

```
@Provides
@ActivityScope
DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener provideListener(DashboardMenuPresenter dashboardMenuPresenter){
    return dashboardMenuPresenter;
}
```

**EDIT**
Because with my answer you are getting `Found a dependency cycle` error, which makes sense. I suggest that you remove `DashboardMenuContract.OnGetAllDashboardMenuListener onGetAllDashboardMenuListener` in the `DashboardMenuInteractor` constructor, and provide it with setter method. I don't think its the best solution, but it will solve you the problem. The downside is that you have to set the listener manually in the Presenter.

Comment: when i update my Module with this getting `error: Found a dependency cycle`

Comment: That makes sense, i am going to update my answer now.